# Custom validation messages for standard validators in Symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I want to override only one message in symfony2 default validation message which is :

> This value should be the user current password.

this message has as a key `security.validator.user_password` I tried to override this message by creating `BundleName/Resources/config/security.yml`.

**BundleName/Resources/config/security.yml**

```
security:
    validator:
        user_password: custom message
```

I tried xml file and cleared the cache but I get nothing.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override using the validation.yml file in your bundle config like said on symfony2 doc.

```
### src/UserBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\UserBundle\Form\Model\ChangePassword:
properties:
   oldPassword:
       - Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword:
           message: "Wrong value for your current password"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this when using FOSUserBundle as a parent to my Users bundle:

```
# Acme\UsersBundle\config\validation.yml
Acme\UsersBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        password:
            - Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword:
                message: Please check your current password and try again
```

This pattern can be used to override any of the default strings which are shown when validation on a given field *in that entity* fails.

So to clarify:

- Acme\UsersBundle\Entity\User: the Entity on which validation is carried out
- password: the name of the entity attribute you're validating
- Symfony\etc: the class which is actually doing the validation
- message: What you want to override with

Hope this helps!